# R-Plot Grid Legend Editing

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have an R Project where I need to plot nine schools on one page so I used plot_grid to assist. The code below is based on dummy data:

```
#dataframes
df1 <- data.frame(acro=c('school1','school1','school1','school1','school1','school1','school1','school1','school1','school1','school1','school1','school1','school1','school1','school1'),condition=c('long condition that has to be spelled out 1','long condition that has to be spelled out 1','long condition that has to be spelled out 1','long condition that has to be spelled out 1','long condition that has to be spelled out 2','long condition that has to be spelled out 2','long condition that has to be spelled out 2','long condition that has to be spelled out 2','long condition that has to be spelled out 3','long condition that has to be spelled out 3','long condition that has to be spelled out 3','long condition that has to be spelled out 3','long condition that has to be spelled out 4','long condition that has to be spelled out 4', 'long condition that has to be spelled out 4', 'long condition that has to be spelled out 4'), count=c(53,93,19,37,60,90,39,19,75,65,24,94,44,16,40,84), score=c(275,530,571,330,306,533,618,774,401,605,356,344,493,778,792,306) ,state=c('state1','state1','state1','state1','state2','state2','state2','state2','state3','state3','state3','state3','state4','state4','state4','state4'))

df2 <- data.frame(acro=c('school2','school2','school2','school2','school2','school2','school2','school2','school2','school2','school2','school2','school2','school2','school2','school2'),condition=c('long condition that has to be spelled out 1','long condition that has to be spelled out 1','long condition that has to be spelled out 1','long condition that has to be spelled out 1','long condition that has to be spelled out 2','long condition that has to be spelled out 2','long condition that has to be spelled out 2','long condition that has to be spelled out 2','long condition that has to be spelled out 3','long condition that has to be spelled out 3','long condition that has to be spelled out 3','long condition that has to be spelled out 3','long condition that has to be spelled out 4','long condition that has to be spelled out 4', 'long condition that has to be spelled out 4', 'long condition that has to be spelled out 4'), count=c(53,93,19,37,60,90,39,19,75,65,24,94,44,16,40,84), score=c(275,530,571,330,306,533,618,774,401,605,356,344,493,778,792,306) ,state=c('state1','state1','state1','state1','state2','state2','state2','state2','state3','state3','state3','state3','state4','state4','state4','state4'))

df3 <- data.frame(acro=c('school3','school3','school3','school3','school3','school3','school3','school3','school3','school3','school3','school3','school3','school3','school3','school3'),condition=c('long condition that has to be spelled out 1','long condition that has to be spelled out 1','long condition that has to be spelled out 1','long condition that has to be spelled out 1','long condition that has to be spelled out 2','long condition that has to be spelled out 2','long condition that has to be spelled out 2','long condition that has to be spelled out 2','long condition that has to be spelled out 3','long condition that has to be spelled out 3','long condition that has to be spelled out 3','long condition that has to be spelled out 3','long condition that has to be spelled out 4','long condition that has to be spelled out 4', 'long condition that has to be spelled out 4', 'long condition that has to be spelled out 4'), count=c(53,93,19,37,60,90,39,19,75,65,24,94,44,16,40,84), score=c(275,530,571,330,306,533,618,774,401,605,356,344,493,778,792,306) ,state=c('state1','state1','state1','state1','state2','state2','state2','state2','state3','state3','state3','state3','state4','state4','state4','state4'))

df4 <- data.frame(acro=c('school4','school4','school4','school4','school4','school4','school4','school4','school4','school4','school4','school4','school4','school4','school4','school4'),condition=c('long condition that has to be spelled out 1','long condition that has to be spelled out 1','long condition that has to be spelled out 1','long condition that has to be spelled out 1','long condition that has to be spelled out 2','long condition that has to be spelled out 2','long condition that has to be spelled out 2','long condition that has to be spelled out 2','long condition that has to be spelled out 3','long condition that has to be spelled out 3','long condition that has to be spelled out 3','long condition that has to be spelled out 3','long condition that has to be spelled out 4','long condition that has to be spelled out 4', 'long condition that has to be spelled out 4', 'long condition that has to be spelled out 4'), count=c(53,93,19,37,60,90,39,19,75,65,24,94,44,16,40,84), score=c(275,530,571,330,306,533,618,774,401,605,356,344,493,778,792,306) ,state=c('state1','state1','state1','state1','state2','state2','state2','state2','state3','state3','state3','state3','state4','state4','state4','state4'))

df5 <- data.frame(acro=c('school5','school5','school5','school5','school5','school5','school5','school5','school5','school5','school5','school5','school5','school5','school5','school5'),condition=c('long condition that has to be spelled out 1','long condition that has to be spelled out 1','long condition that has to be spelled out 1','long condition that has to be spelled out 1','long condition that has to be spelled out 2','long condition that has to be spelled out 2','long condition that has to be spelled out 2','long condition that has to be spelled out 2','long condition that has to be spelled out 3','long condition that has to be spelled out 3','long condition that has to be spelled out 3','long condition that has to be spelled out 3','long condition that has to be spelled out 4','long condition that has to be spelled out 4', 'long condition that has to be spelled out 4', 'long condition that has to be spelled out 4'), count=c(53,93,19,37,60,90,39,19,75,65,24,94,44,16,40,84), score=c(275,530,571,330,306,533,618,774,401,605,356,344,493,778,792,306) ,state=c('state1','state1','state1','state1','state2','state2','state2','state2','state3','state3','state3','state3','state4','state4','state4','state4'))

df6 <- data.frame(acro=c('school6','school6','school6','school6','school6','school6','school6','school6','school6','school6','school6','school6','school6','school6','school6','school6'),condition=c('long condition that has to be spelled out 1','long condition that has to be spelled out 1','long condition that has to be spelled out 1','long condition that has to be spelled out 1','long condition that has to be spelled out 2','long condition that has to be spelled out 2','long condition that has to be spelled out 2','long condition that has to be spelled out 2','long condition that has to be spelled out 3','long condition that has to be spelled out 3','long condition that has to be spelled out 3','long condition that has to be spelled out 3','long condition that has to be spelled out 4','long condition that has to be spelled out 4', 'long condition that has to be spelled out 4', 'long condition that has to be spelled out 4'), count=c(53,93,19,37,60,90,39,19,75,65,24,94,44,16,40,84), score=c(275,530,571,330,306,533,618,774,401,605,356,344,493,778,792,306) ,state=c('state1','state1','state1','state1','state2','state2','state2','state2','state3','state3','state3','state3','state4','state4','state4','state4'))

df7 <- data.frame(acro=c('school7','school7','school7','school7','school7','school7','school7','school7','school7','school7','school7','school7','school7','school7','school7','school7'),condition=c('long condition that has to be spelled out 1','long condition that has to be spelled out 1','long condition that has to be spelled out 1','long condition that has to be spelled out 1','long condition that has to be spelled out 2','long condition that has to be spelled out 2','long condition that has to be spelled out 2','long condition that has to be spelled out 2','long condition that has to be spelled out 3','long condition that has to be spelled out 3','long condition that has to be spelled out 3','long condition that has to be spelled out 3','long condition that has to be spelled out 4','long condition that has to be spelled out 4', 'long condition that has to be spelled out 4', 'long condition that has to be spelled out 4'), count=c(53,93,19,37,60,90,39,19,75,65,24,94,44,16,40,84), score=c(275,530,571,330,306,533,618,774,401,605,356,344,493,778,792,306) ,state=c('state1','state1','state1','state1','state2','state2','state2','state2','state3','state3','state3','state3','state4','state4','state4','state4'))

df8 <- data.frame(acro=c('school8','school8','school8','school8','school8','school8','school8','school8','school8','school8','school8','school8','school8','school8','school8','school8'),condition=c('long condition that has to be spelled out 1','long condition that has to be spelled out 1','long condition that has to be spelled out 1','long condition that has to be spelled out 1','long condition that has to be spelled out 2','long condition that has to be spelled out 2','long condition that has to be spelled out 2','long condition that has to be spelled out 2','long condition that has to be spelled out 3','long condition that has to be spelled out 3','long condition that has to be spelled out 3','long condition that has to be spelled out 3','long condition that has to be spelled out 4','long condition that has to be spelled out 4', 'long condition that has to be spelled out 4', 'long condition that has to be spelled out 4'), count=c(95,57,90,92,56,20,33,58,39,31,18,42,77,63,73,29), score=c(408,270,265,515,702,417,495,379,384,253,603,773,675,779,765,760), state=c('state1','state1','state1','state1','state2','state2','state2','state2','state3','state3','state3','state3','state4','state4','state4','state4'))

df9 <- data.frame(acro=c('school9','school9','school9','school9','school9','school9','school9','school9','school9','school9','school9','school9','school9','school9','school9','school9'),condition=c('long condition that has to be spelled out 1','long condition that has to be spelled out 1','long condition that has to be spelled out 1','long condition that has to be spelled out 1','long condition that has to be spelled out 2','long condition that has to be spelled out 2','long condition that has to be spelled out 2','long condition that has to be spelled out 2','long condition that has to be spelled out 3','long condition that has to be spelled out 3','long condition that has to be spelled out 3','long condition that has to be spelled out 3','long condition that has to be spelled out 4','long condition that has to be spelled out 4', 'long condition that has to be spelled out 4', 'long condition that has to be spelled out 4'), count=c(79,62,29,27,19,39,83,91,27,88,88,72,45,51,25,73),score=c(754,735,451,467,261,436,563,310,379,786,528,429,776,548,378,408), state=c('state1','state1','state1','state1','state2','state2','state2','state2','state3','state3','state3','state3','state4','state4','state4','state4'))

    #bubble charts
df1_bubble <- ggplot(df1, aes(x = state, y = score, size = count, fill = condition)) +  geom_point(shape=21) + ggtitle("School 1") + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+ labs(x = "State", y = "Score") + scale_size_area(max_size = 20) + theme(legend.position="none") + theme(axis.title.x = element_blank())+ theme(axis.title.y = element_blank()) + ylim(200, 900)

df2_bubble <- ggplot(df2, aes(x = state, y = score, size = count, fill = condition)) +  geom_point(shape=21) + ggtitle("School 2") + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+ labs(x = "State", y = "Score") + scale_size_area(max_size = 20) + theme(legend.position="none") + theme(axis.title.x = element_blank())+ theme(axis.title.y = element_blank()) + ylim(200, 900)

df3_bubble <- ggplot(df3, aes(x = state, y = score, size = count, fill = condition)) +  geom_point(shape=21) + ggtitle("School 3") + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+ labs(x = "State", y = "Score") + scale_size_area(max_size = 20) + theme(legend.position="none") + theme(axis.title.x = element_blank())+ theme(axis.title.y = element_blank()) + ylim(200, 900)

df4_bubble <- ggplot(df4, aes(x = state, y = score, size = count, fill = condition)) +  geom_point(shape=21) + ggtitle("School 4") + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+ labs(x = "State", y = "Score") + scale_size_area(max_size = 20) + theme(legend.position="none") + theme(axis.title.x = element_blank())+ theme(axis.title.y = element_blank()) + ylim(200, 900)

df5_bubble <- ggplot(df5, aes(x = state, y = score, size = count, fill = condition)) +  geom_point(shape=21) + ggtitle("School 5") + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+ labs(x = "State", y = "Score") + scale_size_area(max_size = 20) + theme(legend.position="none") + theme(axis.title.x = element_blank())+ theme(axis.title.y = element_blank()) + ylim(200, 900)

df6_bubble <- ggplot(df6, aes(x = state, y = score, size = count, fill = condition)) +  geom_point(shape=21) + ggtitle("School 6") + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+ labs(x = "State", y = "Score") + scale_size_area(max_size = 20) + theme(legend.position="none") + theme(axis.title.x = element_blank())+ theme(axis.title.y = element_blank()) + ylim(200, 900)

df7_bubble <- ggplot(df7, aes(x = state, y = score, size = count, fill = condition)) +  geom_point(shape=21) + ggtitle("School 7") + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+ labs(x = "State", y = "Score") + scale_size_area(max_size = 20) + theme(legend.position="none") + theme(axis.title.x = element_blank())+ theme(axis.title.y = element_blank()) + ylim(200, 900)

df8_bubble <- ggplot(df8, aes(x = state, y = score, size = count, fill = condition)) +  geom_point(shape=21) + ggtitle("School 8") + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+ labs(x = "State", y = "Score") + scale_size_area(max_size = 20) + theme(legend.position="none") + theme(axis.title.x = element_blank())+ theme(axis.title.y = element_blank()) + ylim(200, 900)

df9_bubble <- ggplot(df9, aes(x = state, y = score, size = count, fill = condition)) +  geom_point(shape=21) + ggtitle("School 9") + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+ labs(x = "State", y = "Score") + scale_size_area(max_size = 20) + theme(legend.position="none") + theme(axis.title.x = element_blank())+ theme(axis.title.y = element_blank()) + ylim(200, 900)
```

and below is where i'm trying to construct a grid:

```
library(cowplot)
df_grid <- plot_grid(df1_bubble + theme(legend.position="none"), df2_bubble + theme(legend.position="none"),
            df3_bubble + theme(legend.position="none"),df4_bubble + theme(legend.position="none"),
            df5_bubble + theme(legend.position="none"),df6_bubble + theme(legend.position="none"), 
            df7_bubble + theme(legend.position="none"),df8_bubble + theme(legend.position="none"),
            df9_bubble + theme(legend.position="none"),align = 'vh')

legend <- get_legend(df1_bubble + theme(legend.position="bottom", legend.box = "vertical", legend.justification = "center")) 

df_grid <- plot_grid(df_grid, legend, ncol = 1, rel_heights = c(1, .2))

title <- ggdraw() + draw_label("The Full Title of My Grid Here", fontface='bold')  

df_grid <- plot_grid(title, df_grid, ncol=1, rel_heights=c(0.1, 1))
```

and I got this: 
[image]

**Is there a way I can edit the legend so that the conditions are listed on two lines?**

I tried this and it didn't do anything to the final image at all:

```
df_grid + guides(col = guide_legend(nrow = 4))
```

Thank you

Comment: Try adding `+ guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow = 2))` to the code for `df1_bubble` instead? The legend in the final plot is extracted from `df1_bubble1` with `get_legend(...)`.

Comment: What @fausto.siegmund proposed is the way to go. I would only apply it differently: `legend <- get_legend(df1_bubble + guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow = 2)) + theme(legend.position="bottom", legend.box = "vertical", legend.justification = "center"))`

Comment: thank you, @fausto.siegmund! That worked! Do you have any advice on making the keys consistent amongst graphs too?

Comment: Which keys are you referring to? And consistent in which way?

Comment: count. that makes the bubble size.

Comment: If you need the legend for bubble size to also be listed on two lines you can do: `guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow = 2), size = guide_legend(nrow = 2))`.